# ¿Cómo conectar remotamente a MySql de un VPN?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mariadb, nginx, vpn

tengo un problema que tal ves me puedan ayudar.
tengo un VPN https://clouding.io/ con un servidor linux ubuntu.
se instalo el servidor web NGINX para la ejecución de las base de datos MYSQL, el detalle esta en que no me puedo conectar a la DB ya sea por la conexión de un PDO o por algún Administrador de DB, en ambas nos rechaza la conexión.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tienes mysql configurado para que acepte conexiones distintas a localhost? por defecto, en el archivo de config de mysql esta bloqueado para usarlo solo desde localhost...

Comment: como puedo hacer que ese archivo config se desbloquee para que deje de ser localhost??

Comment: Pues en principio seria mirar el archivo /etc/mysql/my.cnf, y comentar la linea `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`, y reiniciar el servidor. Con eso permites que el servidor admita conexiones externas. No suele ser lo habitual (normalmente dejas acceso a tu aplicacion y es ella la que accede mediante localhost a la bbdd).